# Replace rows in specified slices of 3d array

Tags: matlab

Let `A` be a `n x n x m` 3d array, `B` a `n x n` matrix, and `sel` a `n x 1` column with one slice index (in `1..m`) for each row of `B`.

I am replacing the rows of `A` in the slices specified by `sel` by the rows of `B`:

```
for i = 1:n
    A(i,:,sel(i)) = B(i,:);
end
```

I would like to know if there is a way of using `sel` to directly access the elements of `A` that need to be replaced, without for loop?

Comment: Please provide the implementation using for loops, and a simple example. Your explanations are unclear to me.

Comment: Do you mean `A(i,j,k) = B(i,j)` for all `i,j` if `k` is in `sel`?

Comment: Please provide your work and references on this so far.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. The interpretation given by Sheljohn is the one I wanted. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way of vectorising this, but I would strongly recommend not to use it, because it is unclear, and I don't think it is significantly faster:

```
ind = bsxfun( @plus, (1:n)' + n*n*(sel-1), n*(0:n-1) );
A(ind) = B;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the one I wanted. I played around a bit with the solution and problems of various size, and it indeed seems that the two are about equally fast... That's too bad, but also good to know!

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution**

```
A(:,:,sel) = repmat(B,1,1,sum(sel))
```

**Code example**

```
%defines input
m = 4; n = 2;
A = zeros(n,n,2);
A(:,:,1) = [0.6892, 0.4505; 0.7482, 0.0838];
A(:,:,2) = [0.2290, 0.1524; 0.9133, 0.8258];
A(:,:,3) = [0.5383, 0.0782; 0.9961, 0.4427];
A(:,:,4) = [0.1067, 0.0046; 0.9619, 0.7749];
B =   [0.8173, 0.0844; 0.8687, 0.3998];
sel = logical([1,0,1,0]);

%perform operation
A(:,:,sel) = repmat(B,1,1,sum(sel))
```

**result**

```
B =
0.8173    0.0844
0.8687    0.3998

A(:,:,1) =
0.8173    0.0844
0.8687    0.3998

A(:,:,2) =
0.2290    0.1524
0.9133    0.8258

A(:,:,3) =
0.8173    0.0844
0.8687    0.3998

A(:,:,4) =
0.1067    0.0046
0.9619    0.7749
```

Comment: I take it that I was not clear enough when asking the question (sorry about that!). I wanted to apply the replacement row by row, see Sheljohn's clarifying comment's above for a mathematically more precise statement. Otherwise as good solution for a slightly different problem :)